# get data from mongodb and convert it to PDF

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working on a project using **NODE JS** and **Mongoose**. I want to get data from my **MongoDB** e.g **(all customers store in my MongoDB)** and generate a **pdf** file from this data. Something like this:

```
    Customer.find(function(err,doc){
    var document = {
        data:doc,
        path: "../pdf/PI_Request.pdf"
    };
    pdf.create(document)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        });
})
```

After a bit search, I find **pdf-creator-node** module, but I don't know how to use it. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/0.1/examples/textDecorations.js), here is an example
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/0.1/examples/textDecorations.js